# Cannot find the method of a class implemented using generics when the variable type is String

Tags: java, generics, linked-list, queue

I'm working on some code for a class of mine, and they gave us some code to test if what we wrote works. I edited it a little to make sure that the method I was implementing worked (added the "q2.rotate(2);" line and then an extra print line), but when I compile the tester it tells me

error: cannot find symbol
q2.rotate(2);
^
symbol:   method rotate(int)
location: variable q2 of type Queue

And I'm not sure how to fix this? Is this something I'll need to change in the code I'm working on, or should I just change the variable type in the tester and try to avoid the problem (lol)?

This is the code I've worked on specifically:

```
public class CircularLinkedQueue<E> implements Queue<E> {

    private static class Elem<T> {

        private T value;
        private Elem<T> next;

        private Elem(T value, Elem<T> next) {
            this.value = value;
            this.next = next;
        }
    }

    public CircularLinkedQueue () {
        front = rear = null;
    }

    private Elem<E> front;
    private Elem<E> rear;

public void enqueue(E value) {

        if (value == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }

        Elem<E> newElem;
        newElem = new Elem<E>(value, null );

        if (rear == null) {
            front = rear = newElem;
        } else {
            rear.next = newElem;
            rear = newElem;
        }
    }

public E dequeue() {
        E result = front.value;

        if (front.next == null) {
            front = rear = null;
        } else {
            front = front.next;
        }

        return result;
    }
   

    public void rotate(int n){
        if (n==0){
            return;
        }
        Elem<E> current= front;
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
            if(current==null){
                break;
            }
            current=current.next;
        }

        if (current==null){
            return;
        }
        Elem<E> nthNode=current;

        current=current.next;

        current.next=front;
        front=nthNode.next;
        nthNode.next=null;
    }

@Override
    public String toString() {
        String str = "[";
        Elem<E> p = front;

        while (p != null) {
            if (p != front) {
                str += ", ";
            }
            str += p.value;
            p = p.next;
        }
        str += "]";
        return str;
    }

}
```

And this is the tester I edited:

```
public class D4Q1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Queue<String> q2 = new CircularLinkedQueue<String>();
        q2.enqueue("A");
        q2.enqueue("B");
        q2.enqueue("C");
        q2.enqueue("D");
        q2.enqueue("E");
        q2.enqueue("F");
        System.out.println(q2);
        q2.dequeue();
        q2.dequeue();
        System.out.println(q2);
        q2.rotate(2);
        System.out.println(q2);
    }   
}
```

And this is the code I was provided for the interface Queue:

```
public interface Queue<E> {
    boolean isEmpty();
    void enqueue(E o);
    E dequeue();
}
```

If someone could show me how to fix this problem and explain to me exactly why it's happening, that would be great! (I apologize in advance if I misused any terms; I'm an anglophone learning Java in French so I don't really have a good grasp on the vocabulary)

Comment: The method `rotate` is not part of your `Queue` interface, therefor you can not call it on an Object like `Queue<String> q2`. Either move it into the Interface, or declare your variable with the type where the method is declared, like `CircularLinkedQueue<String> q2`

Comment: Variable `q2` has the static type `Queue`, and interface `Queue` does not define a method `void rotate(int)`. This is not related to generics, but to inheritance.